# passing text into a user-defined function in R Studio

Tags: r, string, function

I am new to R. I want to set up some functions to generate graphs and accept text as an argument, so that it becomes the title. I would like to add the text into the variables xTitle and MainTitle ... And, I cannot manage it.

## function to create histogrm with defined number of breaks

```
REDhistogramNamed<-function(x, y, xTitle, MainTitle) {
   h<-hist(x, breaks=y, col="red", xlab=xTitle, main=MainTitle) 
   xfit<-seq(min(x),max(x),length=40) 
   yfit<-dnorm(xfit,mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x)) 
   yfit <- yfit*diff(h$mids[1:2])*length(x) 
   lines(xfit, yfit, col="blue", lwd=2)
   return(h)
}
```

In the end this is what I got.

```
REDhistogram<-function(x, y, MainTitle, xTitle) {
  MainTitle<-eval(parse(text = "MainTitle"))
  xTitle<-eval(parse(text = "xTitle"))

  h<-hist(x, breaks=y, col="red", xlab=xTitle, 
          main=MainTitle) 
  xfit<-seq(min(x),max(x),length=40) 
  yfit<-dnorm(xfit,mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x)) 
  yfit <- yfit*diff(h$mids[1:2])*length(x) 
  lines(xfit, yfit, col="blue", lwd=2)
  (h)
}

a <-runif(1000,0,1000)   
REDhistogram(a,15,"main title", "xtitle")
```

I managed to get it to work in the end. I think I was just tired

Comment: I tried `REDhistogramNamed(iris[,1], 3, "x Label", "Main Label")` and the text displayed for me.

Comment: How exactly are you calling the function? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Man! I tried it again and it worked. I must have been totally goggle eyed! I tried it out on just one variable using the following.

Comment: a <-runif(1000,0,1000)

Comment: REDhistogram(a,15,"fff")

Comment: I managed to get it to work )) I think I was just tired. Now, my challenge is to find out how to close the question ((